# Convert JSON Lines to JSON array using Apache Nifi

Tags: arrays, json, apache, apache-nifi, schemaless

I have a file that includes (schemaless) JSON Lines encoded data.

For example:

```
{"foo" : "abc", "bar" : "def" }
{"foo" : "xyz" }
{"foo" : "ghi", "bar" : "jkl", "name" : "The Dude"}
```

I would like to use NIFI to convert this into a JSON array:

```
[{"foo" : "abc", "bar" : "def" },{"foo" : "xyz" },{"foo" : "ghi", "bar" : "jkl", "name" : "The Dude"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this in Apache NiFi is to use two `ReplaceText` processors. In the first, configure as:

- Search Value: `\}\s*\{`
- Replacement Value: `\},\{`
- Replacement Strategy: `Regex Replace`
- Evaluation Mode: `Entire Text`

This will remove the line breaks between the tuples and insert commas between them. In the second:

- Search Value: `(^.*$)`
- Replacement Value: `[$1]`
- Replacement Strategy: `Regex Replace`
- Evaluation Mode: `Entire Text`

This will add the enclosing brackets around the JSON array. There are other ways to accomplish this with `ExecuteScript` or `JoltTransformJSON` processors, but they are more complicated and brittle.